# How to detect "Over Current" event of an USB device?

Tags: c++, linux, usb, libusb

I have to detect the event "over current" of an USB device.

I'm developing in a Linux system and C/C++ language.

How do I do that?

Comment: This is completely dependent on the device. It's like asking us to fix a car without telling what car.

Comment: nightcracker's right. The USB library you use to access the device (if you do use a library), is important as well

Comment: I'm using libusb-0.1.13 of course!

Comment: oh, libusb-0.1.13, of course! How could we be so silly as to not realize.

Comment: This is dependent on the OS, and the USB host driver, but not on the device.  It's like asking us to find out which cars are speeding.  You have to tell us what road to put the speed trap on, but you don't need to know the make and model of each car on the road.

Comment: Agree. You might not even _have_ a device driver. A fork is perfectly capable of creating an overcurrent event, and very few forks come with USB device drivers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `uevents`. Here is some [tutorial](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/).
For watching `uevents` you have to bind specific `NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT`:

```
int create_socket()
{
    int                sock   = -1;
    int                result = 0;
    struct sockaddr_nl snl;

    memset(&snl, 0x00, sizeof(struct sockaddr_nl));
    snl.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    snl.nl_pid    = getpid();
    snl.nl_groups = -1;

    sock = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT);
    if (sock != -1)
    {
        result = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &snl, sizeof(struct sockaddr_nl));
        if (result < 0)
        {
            dbg("bind failed, exit\n");
            close(sock);
            sock = -1;
        }
    }
    else
        dbg("error getting socket, exit\n");
    return sock;
}

int main() {
...    
    sock = create_socket();
    while(sock != -1)
    {
        buflen = recv(sock, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        // parse buffer for event description
        ...
    }
}
```

One of the events for sure will indicate the over-current state.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to look at the source code for your particular root port / host controller.

For example: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb/msg49451.html explains the overcurrent detection using a particular host controller driver.

Comment: Thank you, but it is in the kernel?!? Is there an usable interface for user-space?

Comment: @Gianfranco: Every user-space interface to the kernel has some kernel-side code.  If it exists, you'll find it by looking at the driver.  If it's uevents, then look at Rajish's answer to see how to receive those in userspace.  But it might easily use `/proc/bus/usb` or some other interface.  I can't tell you if your driver has a user-space interface, because I don't know what driver your system uses.